# resizing multiple highcharts in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I have the following html table setup

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class='plot1'>Some data 1</td>
            <td class='plot2'>Some data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='plot3'>Some data 3</td>
            <td class='plot4'>Some data 4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

with the following CSS

```
.plot1,.plot2,.plot3,.plot4{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

On a double click in any of the 4 table cells (these will contain chart objects) I would like to expand that cell to fill up the parent div and hiding the other 3 cells. On a subsequent double click I would like the table to have its original setup.

Here is the jQuery for just a double click on plot 1.

```
$('td.plot1').dblclick(function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    if ($(this).closest('table').children('tbody').children('tr').children('td.plot2,td.plot3,td.plot4').is(":visible")) {
      $(this).closest('table').children('tbody').children('tr').children('td.plot1').height('100%');

    } else {
      $(this).closest('table').children('tbody').children('tr').children('td.plot1').height('50%');

    }

    $(this).closest('table')
      .children('tbody')
      .children('tr')
      .children('td.plot2,td.plot3,td.plot4')
      .toggle();

  }
});
```

A working example of the above can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1rv93dhz/8/).

I am having trouble with a couple of things. I'd obviously like to be able to have one jQuery for a double click on any table cell instead of 1 for each cell. This behavior works fine until I introduce a highcharts object into each table cell then the height of the clicked plot does not change when trying to "minimize" back to its original size.

Any help,or different approaches would be appreciated as I seem to be stuck on this silly issue!

Comment: Hi @Bennett Jackson, Could you provide me with a live example with Highcharts charts?

Answer (score 0):

High charts api has something like `redraw`, this will help you to `redraw` charts when the container size changes. There is an excellent demo which help you to achieve it, [Chart resize fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-redraw/).

You can also go through the official documentation [Here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw)